# Explain why $\lim ({a_n}^k)={(\lim(a_n))}^k$ cannot be used to find limit $(1+\frac1n)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Explain why lim $({a_n}^k)=(\lim(a_n))^k$ cannot be used to find limit $(1+\frac1n)^n$

The condition for this result to hold is $(a_n)$ has to be a convergent sequence and $k \in \mathbb N$, which are both true in this case, because lim $(1+\frac1n) =1$. So why can't we use this?

Comment: Thus $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^k=1$ for every fixed $k$. How is this related to $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$?

Comment: [see my answer to the same question here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1230145/204937)

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/336781/11619) I try to explain the errors students are in the habit of making at this and similar other points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because n is variable, while k is a constant in your property.

What means $(\lim_{n\to +\infty} a_n )^n$? $n$ is both inside the limit and outside, so what is the value of $n$ outside? So this doesn't make sense syntaxically

Comment: thank you! I got confused in the constant and variable part :)